# How to group records per custom defined week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to put together a report in SQL that will run in MySQL.

I have a `companies` table:

```
INSERT INTO companies
(`id`, `name`, `createdDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'company_1', '2016-02-01 04:00:00'),
    (2, 'company_2', '2016-01-01 04:00:00'),
    (3, 'company_3', '2016-04-01 04:00:00'),
    (4, 'company_4', '2016-03-01 04:00:00'),
    (5, 'company_5', '2016-02-01 04:00:00')
;
```

I have a `users` table where a bunch of users work for a specific company in a one company to many users scenario. Users accept an invite to join the company and we capture the date as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users
    (`userId`, `companyId`, `acceptedInviteDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-01-01 04:00:00'),
    (2, 1, '2017-01-02 04:00:00'),
    (3, 1, '2017-01-03 04:00:00'),
    (4, 1, '2017-01-04 04:00:00'),
    (5, 2, '2017-01-05 04:00:00'),
    (6, 2, '2017-01-09 04:00:00'),
    (7, 2, '2017-01-10 04:00:00'),
    (8, 2, '2017-01-11 04:00:00'),
    (9, 2, '2017-01-12 04:00:00'),
    (10, 3, '2017-01-13 04:00:00'),
    (11, 3, '2017-01-15 04:00:00'),
    (12, 3, '2017-01-02 04:00:00'),
    (13, 3, '2017-01-03 04:00:00'),
    (14, 3, '2017-01-04 04:00:00'),
    (15, 3, '2017-01-05 04:00:00'),
    (16, 3, '2017-01-06 04:00:00'),
    (17, 3, '2017-01-07 04:00:00'),
    (18, 3, '2017-01-08 04:00:00'),
    (19, 3, '2017-01-09 04:00:00'),
    (20, 3, '2017-01-11 04:00:00'),
    (21, 3, '2017-01-13 04:00:00'),
    (22, 3, '2017-01-15 04:00:00'),
    (23, 3, '2017-01-16 04:00:00'),
    (24, 3, '2017-01-17 04:00:00'),
    (25, 3, '2017-01-18 04:00:00'),
    (26, 3, '2017-01-19 04:00:00'),
    (27, 3, '2017-01-20 04:00:00'),
    (28, 1, '2018-01-05 04:00:00'),
    (29, 1, '2018-01-10 04:00:00'),
    (30, 1, '2018-01-15 04:00:00'),
    (31, 1, '2018-01-20 04:00:00'),
    (32, 1, '2018-01-22 04:00:00')
;
```

I also have the following data in a table called `activities`. Some users have records that they do activities on almost on a daily bases. Some do few times a week and other do activities few times a month as follows

```
INSERT INTO activities
(`userId`, `activityId`, `type`, `activityDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'commit', '2018-01-01 04:00:00'),
    (1, 2, 'commit', '2018-01-02 04:00:00'),
    (1, 3, 'commit', '2018-01-03 04:00:00'),
    (1, 4, 'commit', '2018-01-04 04:00:00'),
    (1, 5, 'did', '2018-01-05 04:00:00'),
    (1, 6, 'did', '2018-01-12 04:00:00'),
    (1, 7, 'did', '2018-01-14 04:00:00'),
    (1, 8, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (1, 9, 'skipped', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (1, 10, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (1, 11, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (1, 12, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (1, 13, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 14, 'commit', '2018-01-01 04:00:00'),
    (2, 15, 'did', '2018-01-02 04:00:00'),
    (2, 16, 'commit', '2018-01-03 04:00:00'),
    (2, 17, 'commit', '2018-01-04 04:00:00'),
    (2, 18, 'did', '2018-01-05 04:00:00'),
    (2, 19, 'did', '2018-01-12 04:00:00'),
    (2, 20, 'commit', '2018-01-14 04:00:00'),
    (2, 21, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 22, 'skipped', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 23, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 24, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 25, 'skipped', '2018-01-29 04:00:00'),
    (2, 26, 'did', '2018-01-29 04:00:00')
```

I'm trying to create a report based off of the mysql that will give me an output for each company:

1) # of users per week who did activity type **did** per week where the week is defined as starting from the the date the company was created. Not calendar week. So if the company was created on 03/03/17. The first week is 03/03/17 - 03/10/17 and second week is 7 days later until week #x until it reaches the current date.

2) cumulative number of users where the acceptedInviteDate is not null. Just the ones that accepted. So for example, week 3 = week 1 + week 2  + week 3 for that company.

Here is a sample output:

```
   companyId   | week# | users_with_activity_type_did | totalUsersdWhoAcceptedAnInvite
    1          | 1     | 0                            | 0
    1          | 48    | 0                            | 0
    ....
    1          | 49    | 3                            | 28
    1          | 50    | 3                            | 29
    1          | 51    | 0                            | 30
```

Please see the latest fiddle started by user Sentinel --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/1

The data inserted is correct but the sql is wrong and returns wrong data

Comment: So the `week#` should be a dynamic increment based on the companies startdate until to current date.. What should happen with the increment if it crosses multiple years because your sample output does not show that case.

Comment: Thank you for your question. It will just increment like week 124,125,127....205,207. Hope that helps and thank you for looking.

Comment: Store dates as dates. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does the week start at 4am or whatever time the company was created, or does the week start at midnight?

Comment: Based on your sample data user 1 and user 2 worked for company_1 before company_1 was created.

Comment: The work week starts midnight UTC which is what every record is stored as.  I updated the sample data to reflect that companies were created before the users data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the provided sample data.

To make this work a Weeks dimension table is needed. Note, however, that based on the sample data users 1 and 2 started working for Company_1 before company_1 was created, so the Weeks table needs to have some negative week numbers to pick up that data.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/17) for complete setup and example code.

**Additional MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table ones (num bigint);
insert into ones values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

create table weeks as
select o.num + t.num * 10 + h.num * 100 week_no
  from ones o, ones t, ones h order by 1;
insert into weeks select -num from ones where num > 0;

drop table ones;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select c.id companyid
     , n.week_no
     , count(distinct case when a.type = 'did' then a.userid end) users_with_activity_type_did
     , count(distinct case when a.type = 'commit' then a.userid end) users_with_activity_type_commit
     , count(distinct case when a.type = 'skipped' then a.userid end) users_with_activity_type_skip
     , count(distinct case when u.acceptedInviteDate < (c.createdDate + interval (7*(n.week_no+1)) day)
            then u.userid
       end) totalUsersWhoAcceptedAnInvite
 from companies c
cross join weeks n
 left join users u
   on u.companyid = c.id
 left join activities a
   on a.userid = u.userid
  -- and a.type = 'did'
  and (c.createdDate + interval (7*n.week_no) day) <= a.activitydate
  and a.activitydate < (c.createdDate + interval (7*(n.week_no+1)) day)
group by c.id
    , n.week_no with rollup
having max(case when u.acceptedInviteDate < (c.createdDate + interval (7*(n.week_no+1)) day)
                 and u.acceptedInviteDate >= (c.createdDate + interval (7*(n.week_no)) day)
                then 1
                when a.activityid is not null then 1
                else 0
       end) = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/17/0)**:

```
| companyid | week_no | users_with_activity_type_did | users_with_activity_type_commit | users_with_activity_type_skip | totalUsersWhoAcceptedAnInvite |
|-----------|---------|------------------------------|---------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|         1 |      47 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             1 |
|         1 |      48 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             4 |
|         1 |     100 |                            2 |                               2 |                             0 |                             5 |
|         1 |     101 |                            2 |                               1 |                             0 |                             6 |
|         1 |     102 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             8 |
|         1 |     103 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             9 |
|         1 |     104 |                            2 |                               0 |                             2 |                             9 |
|         1 |  (null) |                            2 |                               2 |                             2 |                             9 |
|         2 |      52 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             1 |
|         2 |      53 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             5 |
|         2 |  (null) |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             5 |
|         3 |      39 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             4 |
|         3 |      40 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                             9 |
|         3 |      41 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                            17 |
|         3 |      42 |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                            18 |
|         3 |  (null) |                            0 |                               0 |                             0 |                            18 |
|    (null) |  (null) |                            2 |                               2 |                             2 |                            32 |
```

I've updated this answer based on your updated sample data.  Additionally added separate output column for each activity type instead of filtering the activity type during the join.  You can remove the extra column and add the join filter back in if desired.

Also since the activity and acceptance data is as sparse as it is, I've added a having clause to only report the weeks where users accept or have activity.

The final change is having added the `with rollup` clause to the `group by` clause to get some grand totals.

Comment: I noticed after posting that the final column is supposed to be a running total rather than a period total.  Some additional work will be needed to get that result.

Comment: thank you very much and sorry about the dates. No need for the negative weeks. Need to update the sample.

Comment: I updated the formula for the 4th column to return a running total instead of a period total.

Comment: I updated a new SqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/1. It contains realistic data for when companies are created and when users accepted their invites. Your query returns 0s and there are no negative weeks as you can see. You can see I added some users towards the end during the month of Jan 2018 so the number should go up by 1 during some weeks. I updated the original post sample output.

Comment: How far down the result set did you look?  The first non zero result occurs in week 47 where company_1 has it's first acceptance, then 3 more acceptances in week 48.  The next non zero data point occurs in week 100 where two `did` activities are reported and one more acceptance occurs.  I added a `having` clause to the query so it only shows weeks were there is activity or acceptances: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/12

Comment: On extra tweek in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4431be/17 I moved the activity.type check into the projection, and add additional cols for the other activity types in your Activities table.  Finally I added `with rollup` to the `group by` clause to get some grand totals.  Due to the use of the `distinct` in the activity cols, and the fact that only users 1 and 2 have any activity, the grand totals for the activity cols are 2, while the accept col shows a grand total of 32 acceptances from the 3 companies with any activity.  The last two companies are still filtered out by the having clause.

Comment: What do you add to make all weeks shows up regardless of whether there was data or not since company's start date, like week 1, 2, 3, ....47?

Comment: Nothing, just take away the last six lines which constitute the `having` clause.